# websites that show real world scenarios for OOP beginners so that they can implement them

Tags: c#, learning, .net, object-oriented

Since programmers learn more by implementing the real world scenarios rather then by gaining theoretical knowledge and concepts about programming, I wanted to know that is there any website that tells about real world scenarios for OOP learners so that they can practice their designing skills and implement these scenarios using c#?

Like which can help them making designing decisions for a problem for e.g in which scenario one should use abstract classes, interfaces, virtual overriding etc.

Comment: why don't you search books/teachers instead of websites?

Comment: teachers mostly do not have time for such detailed discussions ... but do you know any books that talk about real world scenarios implementations rather than useless examples such as modelling of  student, animal in OOP structure .. i tried Robert lafore, and herbert schildt but they just talk about concepts

Answer (score 1):

This question is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076336/how-to-gain-real-world-programming-skills-when-you-dont-work-for-a-software-com

or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277106/looking-for-some-interesting-c-sharp-programming-problems

Both of these have many fine answers that should point you in the right direction.
A quick Google search got me: http://sixrevisions.com/resources/10-puzzle-websites-to-sharpen-your-programming-skills/

"Real world scenarios" is somewhat ambiguous, the main difference between tinker toy programs and professional programs is that more consideration is given towards security, scalability, compatibility, resource management, performance, etc.

You may want to consider finding websites/books/classes you are comfortable with that focus on syntax/concepts to use as a reference or guide as you go along.

And as others have already mentioned, the best way to learn programming is to simply start writing a program that does something you find interesting. Simple games (tetris, snake), tools (calculator, file browser), or open-source community projects are great places to get ideas.

Comment: Thanks for giving the previous references .. for sure they will help me and other OOP learners

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in OOP, i would suggest you to use the following tools:

1. [BjueJ](http://www.bluej.org/)
2. [Greenfoot](http://www.greenfoot.org/door)

Jackie Barker has written a couple of brilliant books on this subject. One of them is [Beginning C#: From Concepts to Code](http://books.google.com.pk/books/about/Beginning_C_objects.html?id=M71QAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)

The book discusses a case study in depth and detail for  students and novice programmers who are new to OOP.

Answer (score -1):

A quick Google search for "OOP use cases" results in many links.  There are also online classes from universities such as Yale, Stanford, and MIT which may prove helpful.

Additionally, there are tons of real-world open-source software available for your examination.  You can write your own version of specific components and then compare your code with theirs.  The differences may reveal some wisdom.